# YouTube Video Player Won't Fullscreen

Tags: image, video, youtube

On my website http://aliensstudios.com hosted by Webs.com I put all of my YouTube videos into the blog app. The link to the Videos (Blog App) is here: http://aliensstudios.com/apps/blog
The blog has restrictions for content that can be displayed in the body so I think somehow it uses and img tag to link to YouTube videos. The code to display a YouTube video looks like this:

img height="350" width="425" class="fw_media_youtube fw-parse" alt="YouTube-R6xs9dgr1jI" src="http://thumbs.webs.com/Platform/mediaPreview.jsp?type=YouTube&id=R6xs9dgr1jI"

The issue is the videos will not go fullscreen when you click on the button they just turn grey. I'm wondering if anyone knows what to add to this code to allow the videos to be played back in fullscreen or if its an issue with the container the videos are stored in. This is an issue on other people's Webs.com sites too though, not just mine. I've reached out to Webss.com on four separate occasions over the past month, still no answers. I don't know much about web design or coding but this drives me crazy!

Any light that can be shed on the subject would be greatly appreciated!

-Jim E.

Comment: Are `iframe` tags allowed with Webs? If so you can just use the YouTube provided embed code. Such as `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/itSYSSA82dg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` for the first video on the blog page.

Comment: iframe tags are not allowed in the Blogs app unfortunately, it would make my life 100 times easier if they were.